# IE7 minimizes on clicking links

Tags: internet-explorer-7, cross-browser

I am developing this website for a client. It was working fine till a couple of days ago on all major browsers.

Since yesterday I have been facing this unusual problem:

In IE7, whenever I click on any link on the page (navigation link or anything else), the IE7 window minimizes. When I restore the window, the proper link(the new page) is open and showing. Also, this occurs only if I have one IE7 tab open, i.e: if suppose I have two tabs on the window then it works perfectly.

Also, this works fine on IE6 and Firefox. Firebug shows no errors of any kind when I am loading the same page in Firefox.

Can anyone think of a reason that this could be happening?

Comment: strip it down to the bare HTML/CSS/Javascript that causes the problem and post the relevant code.

Comment: I removed all the Javascript on the page and it all works fine. So, its a JavaScript Issue. 

I was using a couple of jQuery plugins. I will have to get into that source. Though, this sort of characteristic was unheard of for me.

Comment: Were you able to fix this ? what are the jQuery plugins you are using?

Comment: I suppose that it was a bug in the HTML with an unclosed tag or something... it's been a long time ago and never had that problem since.

Comment: Sounds like it could be this issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586139/ie-is-randomly-minimizing-when-a-link-is-clicked

Answer (score 1):

- If you restore IE7 to the default settings, does the problem remain?
- If you disable Javascript, does the problem remain?