# Is there any way in JavaScript to focus the document (content area)?

Tags: javascript, focus

Is there any way to set focus to the document, i.e. the content area, in JavaScript? `document.focus()` doesn’t seem to do anything.

Comment: Is that document inside the top-most window of a browser tab? Is that tab active (or in the background)? How exactly does focusing a document manifest itself?

Comment: 1. yes, 2. yes, 3. by having the arrow keys cause scrolling and by not having anything else focused, e.g. links, buttons, textboxes.

Comment: I think you want `window.focus();`. Scrolling with arrow keys is enabled by focusing the window object...

Comment: It can't be done. Proof - open developer tools (e.g. in Chrome) and focus that and then try doing anything in javascript to wrest focus back to the actual document.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

In [HTML 4.01](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#focus), *focus* is only discussed in the context of elements such as form controls and links. In [HTML 5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#focus), it is discussed much more widely. However, how focus works for documents is mostly browser dependent.

You might try:

```
// Give the document focus
window.focus();

// Remove focus from any focused element
if (document.activeElement) {
    document.activeElement.blur();
}
```

It is very well [supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=activeElement) as well.

Comment: Active Element is pretty well supported. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318415/which-browsers-support-document-activeelement

Comment: Benry — thanks for the link. I still think it needs to be feature tested though, the cost of a couple of property accesses is very low compared to a possible script error. Unfortunately my dev environment has just been upgraded to drop a buch of older browsers (not my choice) so I can't test in old stuff much any more. :-(

Comment: **IE WARNING** - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586139/ie-is-randomly-minimizing-when-a-link-is-clicked

Comment: IE WARNING (like Jossef Harush): Stop using old IE and don't try to fix errors in the software, the problem is NOT yours. Advise your clients to upgrade.

Comment: @Erwinus—it's not necessarily the clients, it's the people who visit their web sites. IE 8 is still around 20% of web traffic for some sites.

Comment: @RobG: Put message on top of the page and offer some upgrade options via: http://browsehappy.com/

Comment: @Erwinus—so find me a business that happily turns away 20% of visitors. Properly applied progressive enhancement will allow older browsers to use sites, perhaps not with all the bells and whistles but they should be functional. Of course if your site isn't a business site that makes money then your support requirements might be different.

Comment: "*Do you really thing* \[sic\] *that somebody that is using an outdated browser is interested in buying stuff from you?*" Yes, actually. Who told you that only people with the latest browsers buy stuff? And supporting customers is about more than just web sales.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the following code works...

```
document.activeElement.blur();
```

Comment: If no element is active, it will return the body element. If *activeElement* isn't supported, it will throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

Typescript-friendly answer:

```
(document.activeElement as HTMLElement).blur();
```

Reference: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5901#issuecomment-396497729