# keyboard scrolling UP / DOWN

Tags: javascript, scroll, keyboard-events

I have this code

```
$(document.body).onkeyup = function(e) {
    var code = e.keyCode;
    if(code === 74) {
        window.scrollTo(document.body.scrollLeft,
                    document.body.scrollTop + 200);
    }
};
```

that allows me to scroll a page up and down with the keyboard.
The problem is that I have to click on the page I want to scroll to activate this function.

Is there a way to activate immediately without the mouse click?

Thanks.

Comment: No because your document does not have focus otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

As @somethinghere mentioned in the comments, the reason the shortcut doesn't work is because the document doesn't have focus.

You can attempt to force focus to `document`, but doing so is browser dependant:
[Is there any way in JavaScript to focus the document (content area)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6976486/477563)

Comment: the thing is that I have not to focus the body but a class called .hidden. Is it the same thing?