# Document .focus() works when a webpage loads, but not when it refreshes

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have an HTML form and I use the `<body onload="setFocusToInput();">` to make sure the input field has focus.

But this only works on a new page, if the webpage is refreshed I lose all focus.

Is there some equivalent to detecting a refresh so that I can reset the focus?

**Updated, here's a small but sloppy copy of the page that reproduces the error**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <style type="text/css">

body 
  {
    padding-top: 100px;
  }


* { box-sizing: border-box; }
body {
  font: 16px Arial; 
}

.autocomplete {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
input 
{
  border: 1px solid ;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 24px;
}
input[type=text] 
{
  border-color: #808080;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  padding:5px;

}
input[type=submit] 
{
    margin-left: 5px;
    padding:5px; 
    background:#ccc; 
    cursor:pointer;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;

    border: 1px solid ;
    background-color: DodgerBlue;
    border-color: #CCCCCC;
    color : #fff;
}
.autocomplete-items {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top: none;
  z-index: 99;
  /*position the autocomplete items to be the same width as the container:*/
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.autocomplete-items div {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fff; 
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d4d4d4; 
}
.autocomplete-items div:hover {
  /*when hovering an item:*/
  background-color: #e9e9e9; 
}
.autocomplete-active {
  /*when navigating through the items using the arrow keys:*/
  background-color: DodgerBlue !important; 
  color: #ffffff; 
  /*when hovering an item:*/

<script type="text/javascript">
} 


</style>
</head>
<body onload="setFocusToInput();">



<table >
      <tr>
        <td>
        <!--    <input id="myBanner" type="text" name=" " placeholder=""> -->
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
            <!--Make sure the form has the autocomplete function switched off:-->
            <form autocomplete="off" action="/cgi-bin/prl.pl">
              <div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;">
                <input id="myInput" type="text" name="myCountry" placeholder="Pick a country..." autofocus>
              </div>
        </td>
        <td style="width:150px;">
              <input id="113" type="submit" value="Go">
            </form>
        </td>
      </tr>
</table>



<script>


function setFocusToInput(){
    var textbox = document.getElementById("myInput");
    //var y = document.getElementById("myBanner");
    //y.value = textbox;
    textbox.focus();

}

function autocomplete(inp, arr) 
{
  /*the autocomplete function takes two arguments,
  the text field element and an array of possible autocompleted values:*/
  var currentFocus;
  /*execute a function when someone writes in the text field:*/
  inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
      var a, b, i, val = this.value;
      /*close any already open lists of autocompleted values*/
      closeAllLists();
      if (!val) { return false;}
      currentFocus = -1;
      /*create a DIV element that will contain the items (values):*/
      a = document.createElement("DIV");
      a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
      /*append the DIV element as a child of the autocomplete container:*/
      this.parentNode.appendChild(a);
      /*for each item in the array...*/



/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    var x = 0;
    var regex = new RegExp(val, 'i');
    arr.filter(str => str.match(regex))
       .forEach(str => 
       {
         x = x + 1;

            var y = val.length;
            var lowerstr = str.toLowerCase();
            var lowerval = val.toLowerCase();
            var n = lowerstr.indexOf(lowerval);
            var z = str.length;
             b = document.createElement("DIV");
              /*make the matching letters bold:*/

              if(n == 0)
              {
                b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + str.substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
                b.innerHTML += str.substr(y);
              }
              else
              {
                b.innerHTML = str.substr(0, n);
                b.innerHTML += "<strong>" + str.substr(n, y) + "</strong>";
                b.innerHTML += str.substr(n+y);

              }
    //          b.innerHTML = str;
              /*insert a input field that will hold the current array item's value:*/
              b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + str + "'>";
              /*execute a function when someone clicks on the item value (DIV element):*/
              b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                  /*insert the value for the autocomplete text field:*/
                  inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
                  /*close the list of autocompleted values,
                  (or any other open lists of autocompleted values:*/
                  closeAllLists();
              });
              a.appendChild(b);


       });



///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  });
  /*execute a function presses a key on the keyboard:*/
  inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) 
  {
      var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
      //var y = document.getElementById("myReader");
      //y.value = x;

      if (e.keyCode == 40) 
      {
        /*If the arrow DOWN key is pressed,
        increase the currentFocus variable:*/
        currentFocus++;
        /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
        addActive(x);
      } 
      else if (e.keyCode == 38) 
      { //up
        /*If the arrow UP key is pressed,
        decrease the currentFocus variable:*/
        currentFocus--;
        /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
        addActive(x);
      } 
      else if (e.keyCode == 13) 
      {
        /*If the ENTER key is pressed, prevent the form from being submitted,*/
        e.preventDefault();
        if (currentFocus > -1) 
        {
          /*and simulate a click on the "active" item:*/
          if (x)
          { 
            x[currentFocus].click();
            document.getElementById("113").focus(); 
          }
        }
      }
  });

  function addActive(x) 
  {
    /*a function to classify an item as "active":*/
    if (!x) return false;
    /*start by removing the "active" class on all items:*/
    removeActive(x);
    if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
    if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
    /*add class "autocomplete-active":*/
    x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
  }



  function removeActive(x) 
  {
    /*a function to remove the "active" class from all autocomplete items:*/
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) 
    {
      x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
    }
  }
  function closeAllLists(elmnt) 
  {
    /*close all autocomplete lists in the document,
    except the one passed as an argument:*/
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
        x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  /*execute a function when someone clicks in the document:*/
  document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      closeAllLists(e.target);
  });
}

/*An array containing all the country names in the world:*/
var countries = ["Afghanistan","Albania","Algeria","Andorra","Angola","Anguilla","Antigua & Barbuda","Argentina","Armenia","Aruba","Australia","Austria","Azerbaijan","Bahamas","Bahrain","Bangladesh","Barbados","Belarus","Belgium","Belize","Benin","Bermuda","Bhutan","Bolivia","Bosnia & Herzegovina","Botswana","Brazil","British Virgin Islands","Brunei","Bulgaria","Burkina Faso","Burundi","Cambodia","Cameroon","Canada","Cape Verde","Cayman Islands","Central Arfrican Republic","Chad","Chile","China","Colombia","Congo","Cook Islands","Costa Rica","Cote D Ivoire","Croatia","Cuba","Curacao","Cyprus","Czech Republic","Denmark","Djibouti","Dominica","Dominican Republic","Ecuador","Egypt","El Salvador","Equatorial Guinea","Eritrea","Estonia","Ethiopia","Falkland Islands","Faroe Islands","Fiji","Finland","France","French Polynesia","French West Indies","Gabon","Gambia","Georgia","Germany","Ghana","Gibraltar","Greece","Greenland","Grenada","Guam","Guatemala","Guernsey","Guinea","Guinea Bissau","Guyana","Haiti","Honduras","Hong Kong","Hungary","Iceland","India","Indonesia","Iran","Iraq","Ireland","Isle of Man","Israel","Italy","Jamaica","Japan","Jersey","Jordan","Kazakhstan","Kenya","Kiribati","Kosovo","Kuwait","Kyrgyzstan","Laos","Latvia","Lebanon","Lesotho","Liberia","Libya","Liechtenstein","Lithuania","Luxembourg","Macau","Macedonia","Madagascar","Malawi","Malaysia","Maldives","Mali","Malta","Marshall Islands","Mauritania","Mauritius","Mexico","Micronesia","Moldova","Monaco","Mongolia","Montenegro","Montserrat","Morocco","Mozambique","Myanmar","Namibia","Nauro","Nepal","Netherlands","Netherlands Antilles","New Caledonia","New Zealand","Nicaragua","Niger","Nigeria","North Korea","Norway","Oman","Pakistan","Palau","Palestine","Panama","Papua New Guinea","Paraguay","Peru","Philippines","Poland","Portugal","Puerto Rico","Qatar","Reunion","Romania","Russia","Rwanda","Saint Pierre & Miquelon","Samoa","San Marino","Sao Tome and Principe","Saudi Arabia","Senegal","Serbia","Seychelles","Sierra Leone","Singapore","Slovakia","Slovenia","Solomon Islands","Somalia","South Africa","South Korea","South Sudan","Spain","Sri Lanka","St Kitts & Nevis","St Lucia","St Vincent","Sudan","Suriname","Swaziland","Sweden","Switzerland","Syria","Taiwan","Tajikistan","Tanzania","Thailand","Timor L'Este","Togo","Tonga","Trinidad & Tobago","Tunisia","Turkey","Turkmenistan","Turks & Caicos","Tuvalu","Uganda","Ukraine","United Arab Emirates","United Kingdom","United States of America","Uruguay","Uzbekistan","Vanuatu","Vatican City","Venezuela","Vietnam","Virgin Islands (US)","Yemen","Zambia","Zimbabwe"];


/*initiate the autocomplete function on the "myInput" element, and pass along the countries array as possible autocomplete values:*/
autocomplete(document.getElementById("myInput"), countries);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Liam That article seems to handle first loading of a page, I can't seem to find any answer there regarding "refresh" or "reload"

Comment: What's the difference between a refresh/reload and the first loading? They should do the same thing

Comment: @Liam All I can say is I lose the focus if I hit F5 or do anything to refresh the page.  So I have to assume something is different.

Comment: And you've tried **all** of the various options in that dupe?

Comment: @Liam Not sure what you mean by all.  I have tried `<body onload=` and including the `autofocus` in the item's definition.  Have tired just one, then the other, then both at the same time.  No difference.

Comment: Maybe related to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6976583/7664765)

Comment: If your saying this doesn't work then you need to complete a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to allow us to re-create this functionality

Comment: @Liam Added it to the end of my question

Answer (score 0):

onload is most often used within the  element to execute a script once a web page has completely loaded all content. However - it can be used for other elements as well.

When it comes to input elements, you can try to use the native attribute `autofocus` - A Boolean which, if present, makes the input take focus when the form is presented.

consider that `autofocus` has some restrictions; no more than one element in the document may have the `autofocus` attribute, and `autofocus` cannot be used on inputs of type hidden, because hidden inputs can't be focused.

Comment: Hello @rashelle I have tried it with the `autofocus` in the items definition as well using both that and the `<body onload=` Same problem

Comment: Hey :) can you provide a code snippet with your input element?

Comment: Added it to the end of my question

Comment: once you added `autofocus` remove the `onload ` .

Comment: this should be the body tag : `<body>`

Comment: @rahelle I have tried it all three ways....Just the autofocus, Just onload, and both together.   Again, my problem is on page "refresh" or "reload" not original load.  Have you tried the code I provided and hit F5? Are you using a different browser?